# modify a mapfile Online

Tags: javascript, html, mapserver

how can I rename files and strings in a mapfile in real time on a web application.

thanks for answers

Comment: Post more details, link to an example file or something. Not many people will know what is Your mapfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate map files for MapServer using mapscript. This can be done in a few languages - PHP and Python seem to be the most documented. C# is also possible.

http://mapserver.org/mapscript/index.html#mapscript

You can also use templating to fill in variables in HTML templates with values from your data:

http://mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html#template

You can use variable subsitution to allow variables in your MapFile to be replaced (with values from a CGI request):

http://mapserver.org/mapfile/variable_sub.html

You can also use environment variables on your server in your MapFile:

http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/EnvironmentVariables